# Ektorp NoClassDefFoundError: org.ektorp.impl.docref.DocumentReferenceSerializerProvider

Tags: android, couchdb, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to use the Ektorp CouchDB library in an Android app and I always get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ektorp.impl.docref.DocumentReferenceSerializerProvider
```

Here is my code:

```
HttpClient authenticatedHttpClient = new StdHttpClient.Builder().host("myhostname").port(5984).username("username").password("password").build();
CouchDbInstance dbInstance = new StdCouchDbInstance(authenticatedHttpClient);
CouchDbConnector db = dbInstance.createConnector("luscinia", true);
```

The exception always occurs on the last line of the above code.

I followed the erktop wiki about dependencies here: http://code.google.com/p/ektorp/wiki/dependencies

Which results in my project containing:

- commons-io-2.0.1.jar
- httpclient-4.1.1.jar
- jackson-core-asl-1.8.1.jar
- jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.1.jar
- org.ektorp-1.1.1.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
- slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar ( slf4j fails without it)

LogCat gives me a warning and an error lines before the exception, maybe they can help:

```
Link of class 'Lorg/ektorp/impl/docref/DocumentReferenceSerializerProvider;' failed
Could not find class 'org.ektorp.impl.docref.DocumentReferenceSerializerProvider', referenced from method org.ektorp.impl.StdObjectMapperFactory.createObjectMapper
```

I don't understand what they mean.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid that Ektorp 1.1.1 is not compatible with Jackson 1.8.
This will be fixed in the 1.2.0 release due this summer. Use Jackson 1.7.7 in the mean time.

Comment: I just realized that and was answering here when I received your tweet. Morality, just use the wiki page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert java coder but I imagine the java object its extending before the exception is not part of the java implementation running on android.  Dalvik is not a standard jvm.
I'd recommend this https://github.com/couchone/libcouch-android library for couch on android.

Comment: I checked and "org.ektorp.impl.docref.DocumentReferenceSerializerProvider" is present in org.ektorp-1.1.1.jar dependency.
I'm already using libcouch to do actions on CouchDB such as starting it/stoping it. The AndCouch class is intended to be used for communicating with Couch with basic HTTP requests but as stated in the comments of the AndCouch class, "AndCouch is a very simple http wrapper library for CouchDB".
I wanted to use Erktop which is based in Jackson to handle my documents.